# Java transaction - commit on conn doesn't

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc, transactions, commit

Suppose I have the following Java code fragment (where something like it is embedded in a legacy app)

```
...
try {
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    updateSales = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
    updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);

    updateSales.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
    updateSales.setString(2, e.getKey());
    updateSales.executeUpdate();
    updateTotal.setInt(1, e.getValue().intValue());
    updateTotal.setString(2, e.getKey());
    updateTotal.executeUpdate();
    con.commit();
} catch (SQLException e ) {
...
```

Assuming this is connecting to an SQL Server 2005 database (with the ms 2005 driver) - is there any reason that the con.commit would NOT commit the transaction?

Comment: How did you determine that it did not commit in the first place?

Comment: No exception - no change is registered in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You haven't shown us SQL statements, so it is hard to say. Maybe you have strange condition in them so database cannot update/insert/delete any records?
2. Check result of `executeUpade()`. It should give you 1 or more if any record was changed
3. Maybe there is TRIGGER on database that blocks such operation. Is it possible to change database from some SQL editor with your `updateString` with hard coded values?